# Cannot increase Google proximity API quota

Tags: google-api, eddystone, google-nearby, google-beacon-platform

I am trying to increase the Google Proximity Beacon API quota and when I click "apply for higher quota", it open a Google form with this message:

> You need permission This form can only be viewed by users in the
>   owner's organization. Try contacting the owner of the form if you
>   think this is a mistake.

[image: Quota]

I am using my personal Gmail account. I tried asking Google cloud support about it and they said to post on SO.

How do I increase the quota?